# missing 1 required positional argument:'self'

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
class Email_Stuff():
    def __init__(self):
        self.emailaddr = None
        self.recipaddr = None
        self.EmailUser = None
        self.EmailPass = None
    def From_Email(self):
        self.emailaddr = turtle.textinput("Your Email", "What is your email address?")
    def To_Email(self):
        self.recipaddr = turtle.textinput("Client Email", "What is your client's email address?")
    def Email_Username(self):
        self.EmailUser = turtle.textinput("Your Email Username", "What is your email username?")
    def Email_Password(self):
        self.EmailPass = turtle.textinput("Your Email Password", "What is your email Password?")
    def Send_Email(self):
        print (self.emailaddr) #these are here for me to see if it is the right input
        print(self.recipaddr)
        print(self.EmailUser)
        print(self.EmailPass)
        import smtplib
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.login((self.EmailUser),(self.EmailPass))
        self.message = "Python Test Email"
        server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,self.message)
```

I have a button connected to Email_Stuff.From_Email and a button connected to Email_Stuff.From_Email etc...

Whenever I press the button to open up the turtle window it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
Fileline "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", 1475, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: From_Email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

But then if I take out the selfs from the From_Email and To_Email etc..

```
class Email_Stuff():
    def __init__(self):
        self.emailaddr = None
        self.recipaddr = None
        self.EmailUser = None
        self.EmailPass = None
    def From_Email():
        self.emailaddr = turtle.textinput("Your Email", "What is your email address?")
    def To_Email():
        self.recipaddr = turtle.textinput("Client Email", "What is your client's email address?")
    def Email_Username():
        self.EmailUser = turtle.textinput("Your Email Username", "What is your email username?")
    def Email_Password():
        self.EmailPass = turtle.textinput("Your Email Password", "What is your email Password?")
    def Send_Email(self):
        print (self.emailaddr) #these are here for me to see if it is the right input
        print(self.recipaddr)
        print(self.EmailUser)
        print(self.EmailPass)
        import smtplib
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.login((self.EmailUser),(self.EmailPass))
        self.message = "Python Test Email"
        server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,self.message)
```

I get this error message (this isnt all of it):

```
    self.emailaddr = turtle.textinput("Your Email", "What is your email address?")
    NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

here is the button code:

```
Email_Button = Button(root, text='Enter Your Email', command=Email_Stuff.From_Email)
Email_Button.pack()
Email_Button.place(x=250,y=210)
```

I'm sorry for the long post

Comment: You should show the relevant code in the button that causes the first error you gave.

Comment: What SimonT says is absolutely correct. Some people have already probably guessed your problem, but in the future you should actually show the code you're running that raises the Exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're hitting the following problem. If you take the following class `F`:

```
class F():
     def foo(self):
         return 1
```

and try to call `F.foo()`, you should get an error similar to the one you're seeing.

```
>>> F.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with F instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

What you need to do, is call `foo()` on an object of `F`:

```
>>> f=F()
>>> f.foo()
1
```

> I have a button connected to Email_Stuff.From_Email and a button
>   connected to Email_Stuff.From_Email etc...

You'll probably need to instantiate an object of `Email_Stuff`, and then call `yourobject.From_Email()`. (If your class `Email_Stuff` also contains the GUI button handler stuff, you can just call `self.From_Email()` from the button handler)

Comment: The difference in the error message is caused by the OP using Python 3, where `F.foo` returns a regular function.

Comment: You can also run the program as F().foo()
This is because in Python functions require () even if you aren't providing any arguments in the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Did you create an instance of the Email_Stuff before calling method ? Because the self is the current object calling the method so it's needed.

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr
    def func(self):
        print(self.attr)

a = A(42)
a.func() # print 42
# or
A(32).func() # print 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Also You can avoid to write "self" in the function, as example:

```py
>>> class F():
        def foo():
            return 1

>>> F.foo()

..: 1
```